# How to avoid hitting home key while typing?

Tags: keyboard

I use a Nexus 7 and in landscape and when typing and when pressing the space bar I occasionally hit the home menu key by mistake. I have used "Imersive mode" but I like the status bar to show with the clock so that is not solution.

Is there a way to move that soft menu to the left of the keyboard or somewhere else so I don't activate a menu while typing?

PS: The Device is rooted

Comment: What launcher do you use?

Comment: @DainBinder Nova Laucher but I'm not tied to it.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2005377

Comment: @MANI Lol, then I would hit the menu key instead ;)

Comment: @meerborg - lol ;) that was just a suggestion. I want to know if your problem solved?

Comment: What is the OS version? Can we assume its the latest because its a Nexus?

Comment: Swift key might help some.  It depends how you type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [GMD Auto Hide Soft Keys ★ root](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/root-app-gmd-autohide-soft-keys.2253792/) as your device is rooted, or try [Ultimate Dynamic Navbar](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-4-0-ultimate-dynamic-navbar.2270198/).

For avoiding permission issues, use App Ops.

Comment: Ultimate dynamimic nav bar did the trick. Right permissions, allows me to keep hacker keyboard and most of all that navbar is out of the way. PS XPrivacy is way better than App Ops and works with most versions of Android

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Microsoft SwiftKey](https://swiftkey.com/) to have a split keyboard and avoid reaching to the home button like this one

[image]

Comment: Tried installing it, needs network access and access to SD storage and need to accept some user agreement when installing. I have Hacker Keyboard installed at the moment and needs no access. From a security point of view I might as well publish my passwords on the internet. Although your solution is creative

Comment: @MeerBorg It needs those things for downloading and installing language packs.

Comment: @MeeBorg : it is very important to accept that to install swift key. and it need internet connection only once after you install it for downloading the language packs

Answer (score 1):

I solved this on my OnePlus 6, OS-10, by going to system Settings > Buttons & gestures > Navigation bar & gestures, then select "Navigation Gestures" instead of the default for the fixed navigation bar.

While this completely removed the navigation bar from my phone, it also leaves a bit of unnecessary space below my keyboard (Gboard) now where the navbar used to be.

[image] [image]

Also, you will have to acclimate to using Navigation Gestures but it doesn't take long & you may, like me, come to prefer them over the navbar anyway.

Nevertheless, my accidental "Home" instead of "spacebar" issue is now solved and my stress level is much lower as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to avoid accidentally touching the home button is to use a soft keyboard with *longer space bar* . For example *Go keyboard* has a bigger space bar that occupies ~50% of the screen width. So space can be touched  long away from the home button.

Comment: As this too needs internet access, as it has in app purchases, its a security issue.

Comment: then try w10 keyboard. no ABCD, different approach but no internet access .

Answer (score 0):

1. You could move the soft buttons using some app like [Pie Control](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jun.ace.piecontrol).
2. You could try not to do anything with the device, and train yourself to memorize the position of the space bar.

   It's not that small in a 7-inch screen, **IF you have average hand dexterity**
   (we must cater to the people with disabilities, so a huge **IF**).
   I would recommend playing [this game](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=klb.android.lovelive_en), rhythm games really help improving tapping precision.

---

Caveat: all app suggestions and links here are to exemplify apps that could help; use your own caution and Google-fu to choose your apps. In no way I am endorsing those apps, or even have them installed. If needed, browse related apps that suit your security requirements.

Answer (score 0):

On a Jusyea J5 tablet running Android 10:

System - - Navigation bar

Enable Navigation bar:

[image]

After that a down arrow appears on  the  bottom  bar to hide the system buttons

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just go to settings, open Language and input, and select Hide.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Some freehand red circles could definetly improve this answer.

Comment: There's no such setting on Nexus 5, Lineage OS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2) and Pixel 3a, Android 12. Based on the shown search history, I'd assume this is on Oneplus 7 Pro which uses OxygenOS. But just to make sure, please [edit] and mention the device model and Android version in case this setting is customized by the manufacturer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to install a custom navigation bar, like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nu.nav.bar&hl=en_US&gl=US) for example (no root required). Then I changed the height setting in it to shrink the bar until it barely appears on the screen.

Now there is a nice dead space between the keyboard and the navigation bar which prevents accidental touches.